# How to change the location of ~/.gsutil directory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

The default location for `gsutil` directory on linux is `$HOME`. Is there a way to change it?

I'm aware of `$BOTO_CONFIG` and `$BOTO_PATH`which serve a different purpose.

Comment: Is there a technical reason? The Cloud SDK are designed to be "user" specific as there are keys, credentials, etc that are different for each user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is configurable via the `state_dir` boto config attribute, under the `[GSUtil]` section.  You can either set this value in your boto file, or you can supply it inline using the `-o` option, [as one of gsutil's Windows test scripts does](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/d7281accc526df971d0c4c66327776b5dd1299f9/test/ci/kokoro/windows/run_integ_tests.ps1#L107), e.g.:

```
gsutil -o "GSUtil:state_dir=/tmp/mydir" cp /tmp/file1 gs://mybucket/
```